# How to convert textbox.text into int or what to use for int only input instead?

Tags: c#, wpf, input, textbox, validation

How do I convert a TextBox to int or is there a box inside WPF that supports only numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert string to int you can use, `Parse`:

```
string text = "1234";
int value = int.Parse(text);
```

Or you could use [NumericUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home) control.

Comment: i don't find numericupdown in wpf, but the parse works perfectly.

Comment: @divfe - It is not part of standard WPF controls, I provided the URL to the Extended WPF toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want numeric input, you might be better off with numbericupdown. Of course, you could just validate the input using tryparse...